# Firefox 114.0 skipping js depencencies which names are redundant in relation to the file's location directory

Tags: javascript, firefox, dependencies

I got a headache solving a weird behaviour I noticed in firefox 114.0.
I'm a bit unsure about the way I could put this question actually.

I would like to know if any of you had any experience with a similar event:
basically I'm using a .deps file where one of the many included files was  `/reports/ui/reports_ui.js`.

It seemed like the web page would totally miss the dependency `reports_ui.js` upon loading without a clear explaination of why it was missing this singular file.

After a few tests it came out that the solution was actually renaming the file to something like `rprts_ui.js` so the file's name wouldn't include a word that is redundant to that of a parent directory.

I don't really know in which terms to put the problem, so I'd really like to hear from you;
this doesn't seem like a normal behaviour and can confirm it doesn't happen on other firefox versions.

Comment: *I'm using a .deps file* I'm confused, what does that have to do with firefox?

Comment: Well, I'm serving the js into a compressed jgz wich in turn generates a .deps file to work. Basically the latest firefox version is not loading one of the files included in the dependencies because of the file name. This also doesn't seem to happen on the beta for the 115.0 version, so maybe a version-specific bug?

Comment: so it works in113, doesn't in 114, and does in 115?

Comment: it seems so, exactly, I've been testing the problem on various browsers and versions of firefox